# Uploading an mp3 audio file to Http Server

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

I am trying to record an audio file from the microphone and uploading the same to a server using MultiPart data POST method. I would appreciate some help.

I am currently working on C# and making the code for Windows Phone 7.

Would deeply appreciate some help and if possible, some code reference as i am a newbie on the platform.

Comment: There are quite many results on this topic that can be found through google. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/b40a60f9-6e50-4ddc-bbd6-9e6bf13df709

Answer (score 0):

When recording from the Microphone, your data is raw `PCM data`. You will have to encode it manually, which may not be an easy task if you want to encode it into an MP3. You could upload the file (example in the link ba__friend` posted) as a WAV, or simply the raw data, and convert it to an MP3 on your server.